# Flutter path is not saving permanently on z shell mac os catalina every time after closing the terminal

Tags: flutter, command

i am using mac os catalina and i created .zshrc file and added the following line for flutter

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/me/development/flutter/bin"
```

this is the content of the .zshrc file:

[image]

but when i closed the terminal and reopen a new terminal, flutter command is not working. so every-time again and again, i need to type **source $HOME/.** to make it working.

is there any permanent solution so that the path will not be removed.

Comment: Can you show the exact line you've added?

Comment: Have you changed the default shell to zsh or are you still using bash?

Comment: @dumazy, i added the exact line

Comment: @abion47, i didnt change anything. i bought one macbook and then i updated to Catalina OS. and today, i was trying to install Flutter and I faced the above issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention that you got a MacBook that you then updated to Catalina after the fact. The default terminal shell for Catalina is zsh, but before Catalina it was bash, and any Mac that was updated to Catalina from an older version still has bash as the default. If this is the case for you, you need to do one of the following:

- Change the default shell for your terminal to zsh with the command `chsh -s /bin/zsh` ([more info](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050))
- Add the path export script to a file named `.bash_profile` instead (same location where you created `.zshrc`).

Answer (score 3):

In my case adding the following to `Users/me/.zshrc` solved the problem:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/me/development/flutter/bin"
```

Comment: THANK YOU, and I want to highlight that after a lot of troubleshooting and updating `.bash_profile` and other files, the solution that worked for me on Catalina was adding the path I need to the `.zshrc` file manually. Trying to add it from the terminal saved it into the wrong profile file (`.bash_profile`).

Answer (score 0):

Writing your export to `PATH` code in the `.zshrc` file is the answer with `Mac Big Sur` but also, don't forget to execute it before quitting your shell.
`. ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open terminal.
2. vim $HOME/.zshrc
3. open another terminal
4. drag drop bind file inside flutter file to second terminal
5. on first terminal where vim is openned add this code
6. export PATH=(copy and past on second termainal path here)
7. Press "Esc" then write :wq! in terminal and press enter to exit vim.
8. close terminal test,open again test with command "which flutter"